# Object(...) is not a function - at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just installed material:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

Imported module:

```
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
```

This [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566835/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-at-eval-platform-es5-js79-at-eval-p) answer says it's because of version mismatch with animations. I'm not sure what to update. The @angular/material is at a later version than angular's dependencies. The answer to that question says to install an earlier version of material but I'd like to just use the latest.

I tried installing an older version of @angular/material and it didn't work anyway.

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/material@6.1.10
```

Errors:

```
core.es5.js:1739 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js (core.es5.js:1739)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tabs.es5.js (tabs.es5.js:1)
```

package.json

```
{
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Update:

I updated to Angular 7 and it is working now.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: For sure, there is no `@angular/material@6.1.10` , after `6.1.0` there is `6.2.0` directly in the `angular/material` changelog.. try instead `npm i @angular/material@6.1.*`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **@angular/material** to your angular cli by using below command->

ng add @angular/material